# how to redirect to 404 for a url of following format?

Tags: php, .htaccess

for some reason I see url of the following format in error_log (might have some sort of attack I not sure)

```
www.mysite.com/They-caught-my-eye/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/?p=2rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/rss/
```

Now what I want is to redirect this type of url to my 404.php page. I mean I want take into account of the number of url parts (number of occurances of /sometext/). If it exceeds lets say more than 10 I would like to redirect to 404 page. I know I can do this in PHP with `parse_url()` function , I am looking for a .htaccess way, will it be more helpful If I use .htaccess than through php file (my index file)?

Comment: yes .htaccess is made in use for this type requirements.. use .htaccess

Comment: I think you're going about this the wrong way. The *default* should be that it goes to 404, and it should only be directed to an existing page if it matches a certain pattern. How you implement this will depend on how your site is handling requests, but .htaccess is certainly one option.

Comment: Yes I agree with okyanet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add into the `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://www.yousite.com/404.php
```

Read it more [here](http://www.htaccessbasics.com/404-custom-error-page/)

Answer (score 0):

Below are two ways you can make use of

this for 404

```
 ErrorDocument 404 http://www.mysite.com/404.php
```

or this for ur desired page

```
RedirectMatch "\.html$" http://www.example.com/index.php
```